# How to change value based on substring in a Text file in java

Tags: java

I want to change the substring value of a text file everytime.
Below Hello.txt file with below datas:-

> ID      **422686**    658658   987451

when I am hardcoding this value is replace by new number like,

> modifyFile("Hello.txt", "422686", RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(6));

The value is getting change and new randomNumeric number in this position.**Below Text file datas is fixed** so I dont need to hardcode the number everytime so looking to change the value **from subsring concept** ,I tried this but while passing the changevalue ,getting Null pointer exception

> changevalue= oldContent.substring(7, 12);

Below is my full code ,Please check and update

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class ModificationTextFile
{   
    static String changevalue;
    static void modifyFile(String filePath, String oldString, String newString)
    {
        File fileToBeModified = new File(filePath);

        String oldContent = "";

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        FileWriter writer = null;

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToBeModified));

            //Reading all the lines of input text file into oldContent

            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) 
            {
                oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
                changevalue= oldContent.substring(7, 12);
                line = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("oldContent"+oldContent);
                System.out.println("key"+changevalue);
                System.out.println("line"+line);
            }

            //Replacing oldString with newString in the oldContent

            String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(oldString, newString);

            //Rewriting the input text file with newContent

            writer = new FileWriter(fileToBeModified);

            writer.write(newContent);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                //Closing the resources

                reader.close();

                writer.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          modifyFile("Hello.txt", "422686", RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(6));
        //modifyFile("coln.txt", changevalue, RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(6));//java.lang.NullPointerException

        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like for every line of the file you are reassigning changeValue. Also, String.split() could be used to find the values for the search and replace better than substring. IMNSHO

Comment: can you add String.split()in the above code and share

Comment: First, I would need to see the first three lines of your input file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method.

The first parameter is `beginIndex`, which is `3` in your case. Also, the second parameter is `endIndex`, which is the index after the last character in your specified string, which is `9` in your case.

So, you should write it as follows: `changevalue= oldContent.substring(3, 9);`

I hope it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Still its showing null pointer exception .I need to replace this value ,i.e,422686 everytime.I did many changes but still not achieved.The substring count should be start from ID .The hello.txt file contains ID 422686 658658 987451

Comment: It looks like for every line of the file you are reassigning changeValue.

Comment: @Ravi Which line does result in a `NullPointerException`? and what do you think the indices `(7, 12)` mean?

Answer (score 0):

first of all the `changevalue= oldContent.substring(7, 12);` line should be after the while loop
i think the easiest thing to do is to get the substring and replace the first occurrence of the substring you got in the text

```
changevalue= oldContent.substring(7, 12);
oldContent.replaceFirst(changevalue,"new text value");
```

for the `NullPointerException` you have to test if the text is not null before calling the `substring` method

Comment: changevalue= oldContent.substring(7, 12);
            
String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(changevalue, newString);I replace but output is showing like ID    6370664 658658 987451  ,why its adding one digit here 6370664 ,Its should replace with 6 character only in this position 422686 here rt.when I am passing RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(6).I should get 6 .why 7 numbers

Comment: set the lower bound of the substring function to 6.

Comment: to get the first boundary you take the number you want and you substract 1

Comment: if the Text file contains the data like ID 03072020 658658 987451,I mean first data should be today's date i.e, 03072020 so i don't want to change that ,I want to change the second number only i.e,658658  .if text file don't have any date in first data and it contains like ID 422686 658658 987451 ,its should change the first data i.e,422686.

Comment: you just change the upper and lower bounds according to the portion of your text you want to replace